# Create a permalink with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, permalinks

I have a textbox where a user puts a string like this:

```
"hello world! I think that __i__ am awesome (yes I am!)"
```

I need to create a correct URL like this:

```
hello-world-i-think-that-i-am-awesome-yes-i-am
```

How can it be done using regular expressions?

Also, is it possible to do it with Greek (for example)?

```
"Γεια σου κόσμε"
```

turns to

```
geia-sou-kosme
```

In other programming languages ([Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)/[Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29)) I am using a translation array. Should I do the same here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
function doDashes(str) {
    var re = /[^a-z0-9]+/gi; // global and case insensitive matching of non-char/non-numeric
    var re2 = /^-*|-*$/g;     // get rid of any leading/trailing dashes
    str = str.replace(re, '-');  // perform the 1st regexp
    return str.replace(re2, '').toLowerCase(); // ..aaand the second + return lowercased result
}
console.log(doDashes("hello world! I think that __i__ am awesome (yes I am!)"));
// => hello-world-I-think-that-i-am-awesome-yes-I-am
```

As for the greek characters, yeah I can't think of anything else than some sort of lookup table used by another regexp.

**Edit**, here's the oneliner version:
**Edit**, added toLowerCase():
**Edit**, embarrassing fix to the trailing regexp:

```
function doDashes2(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-').replace(/^-*|-*$/g, '').toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Added tolowercasing and a fix to the regexp that handles the leading/trailing garbage that can occurr.

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex for doing this job is matching all "non-word" characters, and replace them with a `-`. But before matching this regex, convert the string to lowercase. This alone is not fool proof, since a dash on the end may be possible.

```
[^a-z]+
```

Thus, after the replacement; you can trim the dashes (from the front and the back) using this regex:

```
^-+|-+$
```

You'd have to create greek-to-latin glyps translation yourself, regex can't help you there. Using a translation array is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say for **Greek** characters, but for the first example, a simple:

```
/[^a-zA-Z]+/
```

Will do the trick when using it as your pattern, and replacing the matches with a "-"

As per the Greek characters, I'd suggest using an array with all the "character translations", and then adding it's values to the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

To roughly build the url you would need something like this.

```
var textbox = "hello world! I think that __i__ am awesome (yes I am!)";
var url = textbox.toLowerCase().replace(/([^a-z])/, '').replace(/\s+/, " ").replace(/\s/, '-');
```

It simply removes all non-alpha characters, removes double spacing, and then replaces all space chars with a dash.

You could use another regular expression to replace the greek characters with english characters.